# 403 Forbidden error is received on file upload

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-9, laravel-medialibrary

I'm trying to upload a file in my Laravel 9 application. On the localhost, it works just fine, however, the same action fails when I try it from my application running on an Amazon Linux EC2.

**What I know:**

- The action does not throw any exceptions, it just receives an HTTP 403 error. (I've enabled debug in my `.env`)
- I'm only receiving this error in places where I'm trying to upload an image. Other controllers work fine.

**What I suspect the issue is:**

- I believe the issue is with Apache/server configuration. I've added a `dd()` call in the first line of the `update()` function and it doesn't even get there. The `403` error is thrown before that. see below.

**What I've done to troubleshoot:**

- Made sure the S3 bucket policy is ok (the same controller works fine on localhost)
- Made sure the file permissions are ok (see screenshot below)
- Made sure the `authorize()` function inside the request class returns `true`
- looked at the error logs and don't see anything relevant in there either.
- Made sure `file_uploads = On`, `upload_max_filesize = 4M` and `max_file_uploads = 20` inside `php.ini`

Here is what my controller looks like (the `authorize()` function inside `UpdateContactRequest` returns `true`):

```
    //https://myapp.com/contacts/1
    //App\Http\Controllers\ContactController
    public function update(UpdateContactRequest $request, Contact $contact)
    {
        dd($request); //This does not get executed. The 403 error happens before reaching this. 

        $contact->update($request->all());

        $this->uploadAvatar($request, $contact);

        Flash::success('Contact updated successfully.');

        return redirect(route('dealers.contacts.index', $contact->dealer->id));
    }
```

Here is the `uploadAvatar` function I use to do the upload:

```
    private function uploadAvatar(Request $request, Contact $contact)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
            try {
                $contact
                    ->addMediaFromRequest('avatar')
                    ->sanitizingFileName(function ($fileName) {
                        return strtolower(str_replace(['#', '/', '\\', ' '], '-', $fileName));
                })
                ->toMediaCollection('avatars');
            } catch (\Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\Exceptions\FileUnacceptableForCollection $e) {
                Flash::error($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

How the routes are defined:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/test', App\Http\Controllers\TestController::class);
Route::get('/embed-iframe/{uuid}', [App\Http\Controllers\EmbedController::class, 'iframe']);
Route::get('/embed-js/{uuid}', [App\Http\Controllers\EmbedController::class, 'js']);
Auth::routes();

Route::middleware('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
    Route::resource('dealers', App\Http\Controllers\DealerController::class);
    Route::post('refreshDealerCRMData', [App\Http\Controllers\DealerController::class, 'refreshCRMData']);
    Route::post('loadCRMView', [App\Http\Controllers\DealerController::class, 'loadCRMView']);
    Route::resource('cms', App\Http\Controllers\CmsController::class);
    Route::resource('crms', App\Http\Controllers\CrmController::class);
    Route::resource('leads', App\Http\Controllers\LeadController::class);
    Route::resource('contacts', App\Http\Controllers\ContactController::class);
    Route::resource('attachment-categories', App\Http\Controllers\AttachmentCategoryController::class);
    Route::resource('CRMAttachments', App\Http\Controllers\CRMAttachmentController::class);
    Route::resource('dealers.leads', App\Http\Controllers\DealerLeadController::class)->scoped([
        'dealers' => 'dealer.id',
        'leads' => 'lead.id',
    ]);
    Route::resource('dealers.contacts', App\Http\Controllers\DealerContactController::class)->scoped([
        'dealers' => 'dealer.id',
        'contacts' => 'contact.id',
    ]);
});
```

Here is a screenshot of my root directory (`/var/www/html`):

[image: screenshot of my root directory]

Here are my virtual hosts defined in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerAdmin user@domain.com
 ServerName myapp.com
 ServerAlias www.myapp.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
 <Directory /var/www/html>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin user@domain.com
  ServerName myapp.com
  ServerAlias www.myapp.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
  <Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my IAM policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the exact error being thrown:

[image: screenshot of the exact error being thrown]

How can I further troubleshoot this when no actual exception is thrown?

Comment: are you using the same AWS user when uploading from localhost and on the EC2 machine?

Comment: @matiaslauriti Yes the same IAM user and API keys.

Comment: Can you tripl check that your config is exactly the same between localhost and production? For example, do you have the same environment for `MEDIA_PREFIX`?

Comment: Yes, pretty confident they are the same codebase. Not using `MEDIA_PREFIX ` either.

Comment: So, the error you are getting is literally from the exception `FileUnacceptableForCollection ` that you have in that `catch`? Which exact line is throwing the error? Could you post the full error you are getting even if it just literally says: `403` and nothing else? What output are you getting? Did you check the Laravel logs to see if you have a better (longer) error? Also, when you turn on `debugging`, did you run `php artisan config:cache` if you have already run that command before?

Comment: The error is NOT from that exception. I don't think it throws an exception, because I don't get the Laravel's error page, it just receives a HTTP status code of 403. I attached a screen shot of the actual error message. Also ran `php artisan config:cache`. I'll check the logs again, but last time I checked I didn't find anything relevant in there related to this.

Comment: Based on what you have shown, I am 99% sure you havea misconfigured web server. That `403` is an APACHE or NGINX error page, not a Laravel error page. Check your web server config please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with an AWS WAF rule preventing HTTP post size from exceeding a certain number. Removed the rule, and it's now working again.

Answer (score 3):

For other users who run into mysterious 403 Errors using AWS, here is an approach to debugging this and problems like it.

First, verify if your request is even hitting your application. An excellent way to do this is to try to `dd()` in the `AppServiceProvider`. In this case, it would not have returned anything, which is your clue that it is outside your application. If it would have been inside, continue debugging using `dd()` through your application or logging into the Laravel log.

The next step is ensuring you are hitting the server—two approaches for this when using AWS.

**Using Sampled Requests View**

Aws has a thorough walk-through for [viewing a sample of web requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/web-acl-testing-view-sample.html) - this will allow you to view any incoming requests that AWS WAF has inspected and either allowed or blocked.

**AWS Waf Logs**

Additionally, when setting up new projects, I recommend always enabling [AWS Waf Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/logging.html), allowing you to see which rule is the terminating rule blocking the request.

Both of these methods should be sufficient in debugging this type of error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this 403 issue you were experiencing was having place in a shared hosting. When you create the symlink with php artisan storage:link it contains the full absolute path to the storage/app/public folder. This is what probably causes the 403 response by the server.

The solution is create a symlink with a relative path from the project root like

ln -s ../storage/app/public public/storage